# Sylow subgroups and homomorphism of $S_4$ onto $S_3$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sylow-theory

"It's known that $S_3$ has exactly three 2-Sylows. Show that there exists a surjective homomorphism from $S_4$ onto $S_3$".

Well, I don't know how to start. Can someone help me with this exercise?

Comment: The existence of the surjection is doable more or less easily (what's the unique *normal* subgroup of $\;S_4\;$ of order $\;4\;$ ?), yet the first sentence baffles me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $S_3$ permutes three objects.There is only one set of three objects (the Sylow subgroups) in view. Consider the action of $S_4$ on the three Sylow subgroups by conjugation.

Comment: But the set of the three subgroups isn't closed by conjugation by elements of $S_4$...
Example: Consider the Sylow Subgroup $P=\{e, (1, 2)\}$ and $\sigma=(2, 4)$. Then $\sigma P \sigma^{-1}$ is $\{e, (1, 4)\}$.

Comment: The Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$, which has order $24=8\times 3$ have order $8$ and there are three of them. A subgroup of order $2$ is not a Sylow subgroup. The Sylow $p$-subgroups of any group and for any prime $p$ are conjugate to each other i.e. conjugation is a transitive action on the Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the set of the three 2-Sylow subgroups of $S_3$ :)

Comment: @ViniciusRodrigues sorry, I may have misread the original question more than  once. If it refers to $S_3$ in the way you say, I am mystified too.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "It's known that $S_4$ has exactly three 2-Sylows. Show that there exists a surjective homomorphism from $S_4$ onto $S_3$". Then $S_4$ acts upon its Sylow $2$-subgroups and then the question makes sense: the kernel of this action is $V_4$ and $S_4/V_4 \cong S_3$.

Comment: I have answered my own question right below but I will keep your answer masked as accepted because it was you who gave the main hint :) thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi=\{P1, P2, P3\}$ be the set containing the $2$-Sylow subgroups of $S_4$. Let $\phi:S_4 \rightarrow S_\pi$ be the homomorphism induced by the action of $S_4$ on $\pi$ by conjugation. Since $S_\pi \approx S_3$ it's enough to show that $\phi$ is surjective. We will show that $|ran(\phi)|=6$ by showing that $|ker(\phi)|=4$.

We know that $g \in ker(\phi) \Leftrightarrow gP_1g^{-1}=P_1 \wedge gP_2g^{-1}=P_2 \wedge gP_3g^{-1}=P_3 \Leftrightarrow g \in \bigcap_{n=1}^3N(P_n)$. Notice that for each $i$, $3=\frac{24}{|N(P_i)|}$, therefore $|N(P_i)|=8$, so $N(P_i)=P_i$. So all that remains to show is that $|P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3|=4$.

Let $n=|P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3|$. Since $P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3\leq P_1$, $n$ is $1$, $2$, $4$ or $8$. $n$ cannot be 8 since we would have $P_1=P_2=P_3$. Since $|ran(\phi)|\leq6$, $n=|\ker(\phi)|\geq4$, therefore $n=4$.